# How to set multiple conditions (AND and OR) on imaplib.IMAP4_SSL.search()

Tags: python-3.x, email, imap, imaplib

I need to filter emails and label them based on some conditions.

This is my code:

```
def get_inbox():

    os.chdir("C:/Users/simeone/Desktop/FilterEmails")
    df = {}
    df = pd.read_excel("Filtri.xlsx", encoding='utf-8', sheet_name = ['FROM', 'TEXT', 'SUBJECT'])
    filters = []
    for key in df.keys():
        fil = [ '(OR ' + key + ' ' + '"' + name + '"'+ ' UNSEEN)' for name in list(df[key][df[key].columns[0]])]
        str1 = ' '.join(fil)
        filters.append(str1)
    filtro = ' '.join(filters)
    

    mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(host)
    mail.login(username, password)
    mail.select("inbox")


    _, search_data = mail.search(None, filtro)
```

the code is not complete but that's not the point as the error is the condition.
The problem is the condition.

I import the conditions from an Excel where they are divided in from, text, subject, and then I impose conditions on them.

The problem is that the code select every unseen email, whatever the from test and subject.

I have clear in mind the logic but cannot translate to code correctly.
What the mail.search must do is: AND UNSEEN AND (OR FROM "####" OR SUBJECT "####") which means take all the unseen and put the label on those with have OR "that subject" OR they are from "that person".

In another way, label all those from xxx OR with subject xxx but that are also (AND) UNSEEN.

Comment: AND is the default operator, it cannot be specified.  OR is a prefix operator which takes two parameters.  Keep in mind that not all servers implement the search language well, but you probably want something that looks like `UNSEEN OR (FROM ...) (SUBJECT ...)` for one term.  If you start mashing more than about two or three of these together, you’re probably going to overflow the search stack of the remote server.

Comment: the option you gave me is not working unfortunately..also just to point out that those FROM and SUBJECT are also UNSEEN so if I put OR in that position it simply give me all the unseen rather than the unseen that have those FROM and SUBJECT

Comment: OR is not an infix operator.  It is a prefix operator.  That does not mean what it looks like in english it means:   `(UNSEEN)` and `(OR (FROM ...) (SUBJECT ...))`.  The OR affects the two things that come after it, not before and after.

Comment: oh i did not know that..I have tried `'UNSEEN OR SUBJECT "YYY" SUBJECT "XXX"'` and now seems to work. I do not understand your last statement "The OR affects the two things that come after it, **not before and after**", did you mean only not before? because after it affects..

Comment: In English, OR goes between the things: `x or y`. x and y are _before and after_.  In IMAP Search Language, OR goes before the things:  OR X Y.  x and y _both come after_.

Comment: I did more checks and it is not working..I tried 'UNSEEN OR TEXT "YYY" TEXT "XXX"' TEXT "ZZZ"..since they are all after the OR as I add more and more conditions with TEXT the results should be always more (only in case of AND they might be less)..more emails satisfying many OR conditions..I have then a doubt..might it be possible that they must be different? like 'UNSEEN OR TEXT "YYY" SUBJECT "XXX"' FROM "ZZZ"..I do not think so but otherwise I have no idea what is going on..many thanks in advance!

Comment: OR only takes two operands..  If you want more, you need to chain them:  `OR (X) (OR (Y) (Z))`, or perhaps: `OR (OR (X) (Y)) (Z)` for example.  Technically the parentheses shouldn't be needed but it might help.

Comment: ok thanks for helping..then it is going to be quite hard to make this working in the loop I have, since I do not know in advance how many conditions the user will put..thanks

Comment: This got a bit out of hand, so I'm gonna make this into an answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222379/discussion-between-max-and-luigi87).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the IMAP search language, `AND` is the default operation, and `OR` is two-operand *prefix* operation.

For `AND` you just stick them together: "a and b" is `A B`.

For `OR` that means if you want "a or b", you need to write "OR (A) (B)".  Technically the parentheses aren't really needed, but may help if your conditions get complex.

If you want more than two things, you need to chain the ORs together.  Each one can only take two parameters.  You could write "x or y or z" as either `OR (OR X Y) Z` or `OR X (OR Y Z)`.  Again the parenthesis are optional, but may help some servers parse it better.

Sticking all that together "a and (x or y or z)" is `A OR OR X Y Z`.

There is a lot of server software that doesn't handle complex queries very well.  If your query gets too complex or the servers implementation is marginal, you may want to consider caching the metadata yourself (using `UID FETCH BODY[HEADER]`) and doing your searches locally.  This data is theoretically immutable so you should only have to fetch it once.

Comment: perfect for accommodating three or more conditions